# Download backup to ubuntu

Tags: backup, wget

I had my site on bluehost now moved to vps running ubuntu

I made the backup of my site on bluehost and saved it in public_html directory with permission 755

Now when i try:

```
wget http://domain.com/backup.tar.gz
```

It downloads a very small file and when i `vi` to see what's inside it, it's html code :/

```
<html>^M
<head>^M
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">^M
<script>^M
(function() {  function getSessionCookies() {   cookieArray = new Array();   var cName = /^\s?incap_ses_/;   var c = document.cookie.split(";");   for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {    key = c[i].substr(0, c[i].indexOf("="));    value = c[i].substr(c[i].indexOf("=") + 1, c[i].length);    if (cName.test(key)) {     cookieArray[cookieArray.length] = value    }   }   return cookieArray  }  function setIncapCookie(vArray) {   try {    cookies = getSessionCookies();    digests = new Array(cookies.length);    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {     digests[i] = simpleDigest((vArray) + cookies[i])    }    res = vArray + ",digest=" + (digests.join())   } catch (e) {    res = vArray + ",digest=" + (encodeURIComponent(e.toString()))   }   createCookie("___utmvc", res, 20)  }  function simpleDigest(mystr) {   var res = 0;   for (var i = 0; i < mystr.length; i++) {    res += mystr.charCodeAt(i)   }   return res  }  function createCookie(name, value, seconds) {   if (seconds) {    var date = new Date();    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (seconds * 1000));    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString()   } else {    var expires = ""   }   document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"  }  function test(o) {   var res = "";   var vArray = new Array();   for (var j = 0; j < o.length; j++) {    var test = o[j][0]    switch (o[j][1]) {    case "exists_boolean":     try {         if(typeof(eval(test)) != "undefined"){                 vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent(test + "=true")       }       else{          vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent(test + "=false")      }     } catch (e) {      vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent(test + "=false")     }     break;    case "exists":     try {      vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent(test + "=" + typeof(eval(test)))     } catch (e) {      vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent(test + "=" + e)     }     break;    case "value":     try {      vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent(test + "=" + eval(test).toString())     } catch (e) {      vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent(test + "=" + e)     }     break;     case "plugins":     try{         p=navigator.plugins         pres=""         for (a in p){pres+=(p[a]['description']+" ").substring(0,20)}         vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent("plugins=" + pres);         }     catch(e){         vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent("plugins=" +e);         }     break;      case "plugin":     try {      a = navigator.plugins;      for (i in a) {       f = a[i]["filename"].split(".");       if (f.length == 2) {        vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent("plugin=" + f[1]);        break       }      }     } catch (e) {      vArray[vArray.length] = encodeURIComponent("plugin=" + e)     }     break    }   }   vArray = vArray.join();   return vArray  }  var o = [   ["navigator", "exists_boolean"],   ["navigator.vendor", "value"],   ["opera", "exists_boolean"],   ["ActiveXObject", "exists_boolean"],   ["navigator.appName", "value"],   ["platform", "plugin"],   ["webkitURL", "exists_boolean"],   ["navigator.plugins.length==0", "value"],   ["_phantom", "exists_boolean"] ];  try {   setIncapCookie(test(o));   document.createElement("img").src = "/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e=" + Math.random()  } catch (e) {   img = document.createElement("img");   img.src = "/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e=" + e  } })();^M
</script>^M
<script>^M
(function() { ^M
var z="";var b="7472797B766172207868723B76617220743D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528293B766172207374617475733D227374617274223B7661722074696D696E673D6E65696E675B325D3D22723A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D656E742822696D6722292E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4553324C555243543D363726743D373826643D222B656E636F64655552494286E756C6C297D63617463682863297B7374617475732B3D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B2220
696E6361705F6578633A20222B633B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D656E742822696D6722292E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4554617475732B222028222B74696D696E672E6A6F696E28292B222922297D3B";for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+pa
rseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();^M
</script></head>^M
<body>^M
<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>^M
</body></html>
```

I tried downloading another file, favicon.ico from the home directory, it resulted in the same thing!

Please help ...

Answer (score 2):

Ok solved it.

Bluehost had this "sitelock" enabled which was incapsula thing, protecting it as waf/cdn

I went to addon > sitelock and added the vps ip to whitelist

And it worked :)